# Как реализовать программно XAML код?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть ссылка на кнопку `var button`

```
var button = new Button();
button.ContentTemplate...
```

Как реализовать программно XAML код?

XAML:

```
<Button >
    <Button.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel >
                <TextBlock />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.ContentTemplate>
</Button>
```

Comment: Эх, `MVVM` вам не хватает...

Comment: Зачем вручную контакт создавать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();

FrameworkElementFactory wrapPanel = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(WrapPanel));            
FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));    

textBlock.SetValue(TextBlock.TextProperty, "some text");//добавим текст 
wrapPanel.AppendChild(textBlock);  

template.VisualTree = wrapPanel;

button.ContentTemplate = template;
```

Второй вариант с использованием [XamlRedaer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B):

```
string temp = @"<DataTemplate xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""> 
                    <WrapPanel>
                        <TextBlock/>
                    </WrapPanel>                            
                </DataTemplate>";

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(temp);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader)

DataTemplate template =  XamlReader.Load(xmlReader) as DataTemplate;
button.ContentTemplate = template;
```

Comment: почему в первом варианте ошибка при `textBlock.Text = "1";` &?
`System.ArgumentException: "Не удается добавить текст "1", так как текст не является допустимым в данном элементе."` `  $exception Не удается вычислить выражение.  
`

Comment: @codename0082016, потому что textBlock в данном случае не является экземпляром TextBlock на самом деле. Обновил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: Ого, классно! Не знал, как создавать шаблоны в коде.

Comment: @VladD, я тоже, до сегодняшнего дня)